# Moving scheduled event from one chat room to another?

Tags: support, chat, chat-event, reminder

At [Genealogy & Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com) we are contemplating moving a scheduled weekly event from one chat room to another.

We have 73 users that have signed up for a reminder to that event.

Is it possible to move the event, without losing those registrants and breaking their reminders, from one chat room to another?

Answer (score 1):

Having poked around chat, unfortunately, there's no real way of doing this - events seem locked to a room, and there's no UI that indicates they can be moved.